# Python Borg design pattern, running method on creation of class

Tags: python, variables, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement the Borg design pattern found here (recreated below): http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html.

```
class Borg:
    _shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_state

class Singleton(Borg):
def __init__(self, arg):
    Borg.__init__(self)
    self.val = arg
def __str__(self): return self.val
```

I want to run a particular method on the first initialization of this class, but never again. Originally, I tried using some boolean flag, but from my understanding, the Singleton class is initialized multiple times, but the state and behavior are common among all instances. Therefore, any initialization I do within the **init** method happens more than once, so the flags were reset each time the Singleton method was initialized.

I found a solution that works, but I am wondering what is the most pythonic way to do this, because I don't believe this is it. I did the following:

```
class Singleton(Borg):
def __init__(self, arg):
    Borg.__init__(self)
        if not self.__dict__: #I'm just checking that the namespace is empty, knowing it will be filled with something in the future. 
            firstInitializationMethod()
```

Any help is much appreciated, and please let me know if more details are needed. I'm new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution isn't that bad with the caveat being that you have absolutely have to populate that `__dict__` before next `init` is called again or `firstInitializationMethod()` will be called more than once. It's guaranteed to happen in your example because of `self.val = arg`.

However if your Simpleton would do no assignments inside class instance namespace in its `__init__` call then your solution could fail.

More straightforward and robust way is just to use class attribute like this:

```
class Singleton(Borg):
    _first_initialization = True
    def __init__(self,arg):
        Borg.__init__(self)
        if Singleton._first_initialization:
            firstInitializationMethod()
            Singleton._first_initialization = False
```

You can test this code by just replacing `firstInitializationMethod()` with print and creating some `Simpleton` objects to see that it'll only get called once.

This works and `_first_initialization` isn't overwritten back to `True` on every `__init__` call because class namespace is **separate** from class *instance* namespace and Borg is only affecting the latter(namely making all instances of Simpleton to use the same `__dict__`).

**Followup question:**
*I tried the code with self instead of Singleton and it still worked. It seems they resolve to the same thing. Is there a reason to use Singleton?*

Consider this code using these two approaches where `SingletonSelfless` is the one using `Singleton._first_initialization`, `tinker()` is just returning `self.__first_initialization`:

```
a = Singleton('a')
print(a)
b = Singleton('b')
print(a,b)
c = Singleton('c')
print(a,b,c)
print(Singleton._first_initialization, a.tinker(),b.tinker(),c.tinker())

a = SingletonSelfless('a')
print(a)
b = SingletonSelfless('b')
print(a,b)
c = SingletonSelfless('c')
print(a,b,c)
print(SingletonSelfless._first_initialization, a.tinker(),b.tinker(),c.tinker())
```

and its output:

```
doing some init!!
a
b b
c c c
True False False False
doing some init!!
a
b b
c c c
False False False False
```

From practical point of view both implemenations work like we wanted them to yet there is clear difference with `_first_initialization` variable(s) values.

Answer is quite simple. 
Even though class namespace and class instance namespace are separate, the instance **still can** access the class namespace.
But it only does as fallback - class instance namespace has absolute priority - but when it can't find name in its own instance namepsace then it tries to use class one.
So let's look at `__init__` in this `Singleton`:

```
class Singleton(Borg):
    _first_initialization = True
    def __init__(self,arg):
        Borg.__init__(self)
        if  self._first_initialization:
            print('doing some init!!')
            self._first_initialization = False
        self.val = arg
    def tinker(self):
        return self._first_initialization
    def __str__(self): return self.val
```

Even though the instance doesn't have `_first_initialization` our `if` is being resolved using `Singleton._first_initialization`. 
However setting `self._first_initialization` to `False` creates the `_first_initialization` variable in instance namespace. 
Thanks too `Borg` all our instances share the same `__dict__`, so on subsequent init calls there will be a `_first_initialization` in class instance namespace(the one created at first `__init__` call with value `False`)
and our conditional statement will resolve as we'd want it to - not doing another `firstInitializationMethod()` (here print for demonstration purpouses).

However our original `_first_initialization` residing in class namespace is unchanged. That's why we get `True False False False`.

In `SingletonSelfless`, we are never creating `_first_initialization` in class instance(s) so tinker() call will fallback to class namespace. That's why there are 4 falses - all calls points to the same object(`SingletonSelfless._first_initialization` bool variable).

While in `Singleton` we have two different objects - one from class namespace and the other in class instance namespace shared between instances.
So why use `Singleton.` instead of `self.` ? Well for the starters with the first we 'save' incredibly tiny bit of memory by having only one _first_initialization bool in there!
But the real reason is that it's harder to accidently change variable hiding in class namespace.
If we are using `self._first_initialization` and somewhere later in our code something like this happened for whatever reason(or the _shared_dict from Borg would be cleared or changed affecting that would reside there):
`a._first_initialization = 'Lol'` or in Singleton or its child method `self._first_initialization = 'ROFL'`
then we gonna have some serious problems doing init of new Singleton objects.
With `Singleton._first_initialization` it'd be fine since the variable used for init could be only modified by explicit `Singleton._first_initialization='bad idea'`

Comment: This is partially unrelated, but I tried the code with `self` instead of `Singleton` and it still worked. It seems they resolve to the same thing. Is there a reason to use `Singleton`?

Comment: @thePhilosopher They differ. I'll update my answer in a moment to show you difference.

Comment: @thePhilosopher I've updated the answer with quite a wall of text  regarding your followup question but I hope that's readable enough for you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old, but I just thought of the following solution:

```
class Borg(object):
    _state = {}
    def __new__(cls, hive_name, *p):
        self = object.__new__(cls, *p)
        if hive_name not in cls._state:
            cls._state[hive_name]={}
            self.__dict__ = cls._state[hive_name]
            self.__init_hive__(*p)
        else:
            self.__dict__ = cls._state[hive_name]
        return self

    def __init_hive__(self, *p):
        pass
```

This implementation lets you create multiple shared states (to keep with the theme, I called these hives) and assign instances freely. When a hive is created, it calls the `__init_hive__` method on the first instance in the hive, passing the instantiation arguments. For example

```
class WeAre(Borg):
    def __init__(self, hive_name, arg):
        super(WeAre, self).__init__(hive_name, arg)

    def __init_hive__(self, arg):
        self.hive_arg=arg

# Prints foo
print WeAre("The Collective", "foo").hive_arg

# Prints foo again
print WeAre("The Collective", "bar").hive_arg

# Prints bar
print WeAre("The Hive", "bar").hive_arg
```